# module 'googleapiclient' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, google-analytics, databricks, azure-databricks

I have seen some similar issues but they seemed to be mostly environment related. 
[image]

I am using databricks and suddenly this error came up today(google-api-python-client). I haven't changed anything so I find it really confusing. Re-install and creating another cluster didn't help.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue "module 'googleapiclient' has no attribute '_version__' ", make sure you have installed or updated the Google Client Library.

```
%sh pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

[image]